# Unable to make POST request with files to another php website

Tags: php, request, python-3.5, urllib2

Recently I have migrate my application from python2/pylons to python3/pyramid.

In my plyons app, I was using below code to make POST request to third party  php website (also maintained by me).

```
     register_openers()

     datagen, headers = multipart_encode({
        "biosamples_metadata": open(file_bs_md, "rb"),
        "metastore": open(file_ds_md, "rb"),
        "annotation-submit": "Validate Annotation Files"
    })

    # Create the Request object
    url = config['php_website_url']
    request = urllib.request.Request(url, datagen, headers)
    # Actually do the request, and get the response
    return_text = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
    return return_text
```

This above code worked perfectly fine. However on python3, poster is not supported and I cannot use `register_openers()` which I don't even know do what.

In python3, I am using requests module.

```
import requests
        from requests_toolbelt import MultipartEncoder
        url = config['php_website_url']
        m = MultipartEncoder(
                fields={'biosamples_metadata': open(file_bs_md, 'rb'),
                        "metastore":open(file_ds_md, "rb"),
                        "annotation-submit":  "Validate Annotation Files"
                        }
                )
        request = requests.post(url, data=m)
        return_text = request.text
```

However, this code does not work properly. It goes to php app and executes the part of the code that is supposed to be executed when you do get request.

Here is what php code look like

```
      public function handle_request () {

            $TEMPLATE = 'content_main';

            // Process POST
            if ($this->isPOST()) {
                  $this->_annotationFiles = array();
                   return $this->error_span('This is Get');
                 } 
            else ($this->isGET()) {
                  $this->_annotationFiles = array();
                  return $this->error_span('This is Post')
                 }
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: edited question

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your PHP code, but the below is the correct way to post files & data to a remote url with Python 3 and requests:

```python
import requests
post_addr = "https://example.com/post_url"
data = {
    'foo': 'bar',
    'foo_a': 'bar_a':
    }
files = {'file': open('report.xls', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(post_addr, data=data, files=files)
```